# Let $V$ be a TRO such that $A(V)= \mathbb{C}$, what can we say about $V$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $V$ be a TRO i.e. closed subspace of $B(H,K)$ such that $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$. Let $C(V)$ and $D(V)$ denotes the $C^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $VV^{\ast}$ and $V^*V$ respectively. We define $A(V)$, the linking $C^*$-algebra of $V$ as follows:

$$A(V) = \begin{bmatrix}
     C(V) &  V\\
    V^* & D(V)
\end{bmatrix}$$

> Let $V$ be a TRO such that $A(V)= \mathbb{C}$, what can we say about $V$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$A(V)=\mathbb C$"? Simply that $A(V)$ is one-dimensional, spanning by a single projection?

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think when we write
$$ A(V) = \left[ \begin{matrix} C(V) & V \\ V^* & D(V) \end{matrix} \right] $$
we implicitly mean taking the linear span.  Thus $A(V) = \mathbb C$ means that $A(V)$ is spanned by a single matrix, which is necessarily a projection, as $A(V)$ is a $C^*$-algebra.  So $V$ must certainly be one-dimensional as well, say spanned by $v\in B(H,K)$.  However, if $C(V)$ or $D(V)$ is non-zero, then because we *take linear spans*, $A(V)$ will still be more than one-dimensional.  As $\|v^*v\| = \|v\|^2$, we must have that $C(V)$ and $D(V)$ are non-zero.  So I believe this is impossible.

---

If $V$ were spanned by a single [partial isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry) then $A(V)$ will be four dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matthew!